# Why I got unknown dataSource error in Druid

Tags: druid

I currently have some datasources in my `Druid` cluster as listed below :

```sh
http://druid_ip:port/druid/v2/datasources

[
    "Daily-Trader-Transactions-Rayan",
    "MarketWatch-BookOrders",
    "Daily-Trade-Rollups",
    "MarketWatch-01",
    "Instrument-Monthly-Trades",
    "MarketWatch-02",
    "Daily-Trade-Details-Rayan",
    "MarketWatch-5J",
    "MarketWatch-04",
    "MarketWatch-37"
]
```

When I want to work with these datasources via calling API , I got an error( "unknown dataSource"). Suppose I want to check the `Compaction status` of a datasource :

```sh
http://druid_ip:port/druid/coordinator/v1/compaction/status?dataSource="MarketWatch-BookOrders"
```

the response is :

```sh
{
    "error": "unknown dataSource"
}
```

what I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think the datasource name should be specified without the quotes -

**Eg -**
http://druid_ip:port/druid/coordinator/v1/compaction/status?dataSource=MarketWatch-BookOrders

[image]

Also, It seems API don't recognise the datasource if auto-compaction is not configured for the datasource .

Comment: thanks for your quick response. I apply this solution and the problem is still there.

Comment: have you enabled auto compaction for "MarketWatch-BookOrders" and did any compaction ever ran for this datasource ?

Comment: yes, I enabled Auto Compaction in Druid UI . It's OK?